# A simple rhyming riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Always growing,
>
> Never shrinking.
>
> Always thought of,
>
> Never thinking.
>
> Always trod on,
>
> Loved forever.
>
> Always sleeping
>
> Dreaming never.

Who am I?

Edit: I added 4 more lines to the riddle to make it less broad.

Comment: maybe a little too broad, could be plenty of things

Comment: @Flying_whale I thought some might say that. I'm happy to add some clarification if I see lots of incorrect, but plausible answers coming in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the answer

> People who have died?

It seems to fit every line quite closely

Always growing, / Never shrinking.

> The total number of people who have died is always increasing and always will (barring a zombie apocalypse)

Always thought of, / Never thinking.

> We think of those who have died, but they don't think

Always trod on, Loved forever.

> Maybe not exactly trod on, but underground

Always sleeping / Dreaming never.

> Again, pretty self explanatory

Comment: Close! But how do you explain the "Always growing, never shrinking"?

Comment: The technically correct answer was "A Graveyard". But this is close enough! Great job.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a story told or

> History

Always growing, Never shrinking.

> History increases as time unfolds.

Always thought of, Never thinking.

> We think of past times, but they are history.

Comment: Really good guess. I think my original riddle was too broad, so I added 4 more lines.

Answer (score 3):

I will give a try then :)

 it may be

> the sun

*Always growing,*

> The sun is growing while burning its hydrogen

*Never shrinking.*

> it's growing, not shrinking

*Always thought of,*

> many civilization had the sun in the center of their life, for some, it was a god. furthermore, we see it everyday

*Never thinking.*

> obviously, a star doesn't think

Comment: Not quite! I went ahead and added more lines to the riddle to help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> human knowledge

Or

> the universe.

There are too many possible options, in my opinion.

Comment: I added more to the riddle to narrow down the possible answers.